# React js Display dynamic html in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to display Unordered List inside the Bootstrap Modal in React JS , the list is dynamic.

I tried this way to achieve but it doesn't work the html elements appears as a string

```
var ModalHeader = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
return (
  <div className="modal-header">
    {this.props.title}
    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
)
}});

var ModalBody = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (
  <div className="modal-body">
    {this.props.content}
  </div>
)
}});

var ModalFooter = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (
  <div className="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
)
}});

var Modal = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (<div className="modal fade">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <ModalHeader title="Modal Title"/>
        <ModalBody content = "<ul><li>Make</li><li>Hub</li><li>Market</li><li>Assembly type</li><li>Order Number</li></ul>" />
        <ModalFooter />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>)
}});

var Button = React.createClass({
  showModal: function() {
$(this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()).modal();
},
render : function(){
return (
  <div>
    <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.showModal}>
        Show Modal
   </button>
    <Modal ref="modal" />
  </div>
);
 }});

React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Is there any other approach to display dynamic html inside Bootstrap Model/Popup in React JS . Thanks in advance.

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is what you are looking for. Read it here https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stacks26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2971707/stack26) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373777/react-js-display-dynamic-html-in-bootstrap-modal#comment89719079_51373777), `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` is available if you have a string of raw HTML. Your `ModalBody` component's `render` method would look like this:

```
return (
  <div className="modal-body"
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}} />
);
```

This works, but comes with the inherent danger implied by this prop's name – you have to be very careful where *all* of that HTML is coming from, lest you set yourself up for a cross-site scripting vulnerability.

However, in your example, you have your modal contents verbatim in your code. I don't know if that's just for illustration purposes, and in your real use case that rendered HTML is from elsewhere. But *if* you're mainly looking for a way to "give content" to a component, but it's not necessarily given as a raw HTML string, there are better ways.

First, a prop's value doesn't have to be a string, it can be any JavaScript expression – and that includes JSX. So this works fine:

```
<ModalBody content={<ul><li>Make</li><li>...</li></ul>} />
```

But even better, cases like this are exactly what the magic [`children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) prop is made for. This prop receives whatever you have between your opening and closing JSX tags.

So if you use the `children` prop instead of `content` in your `ModalBody`, like this:

```
return (
  <div className="modal-body">
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

and render your `Modal` like this:

```
return (<div className="modal fade">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <ModalHeader title="Modal Title"/>
            <ModalBody>
              <ul>
                <li>Make</li>
                <li>Hub</li>
                <li>Market</li>
                <li>Assembly type</li>
                <li>Order Number</li>
              </ul>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>)
```

then you're expressing the fact that the `<ul>` is the content of the `<ModalBody>` in a much more natural way, by enclosing it between tags.

You can also do the same thing with the `ModalHeader`.

Here's a snippet that's mostly copied from your question, but uses `props.children` for header and body of the modal:

```js
var ModalHeader = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
return (
  <div className="modal-header">
    {this.props.children}
    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
)
}});

var ModalBody = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (
  <div className="modal-body">
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
)
}});

var ModalFooter = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (
  <div className="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
)
}});

var Modal = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (<div className="modal fade">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <ModalHeader>
          Modal Title
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <ul><li>Make</li><li>Hub</li><li>Market</li><li>Assembly type</li><li>Order Number</li></ul>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>)
}});

var Button = React.createClass({
  showModal: function() {
$(this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()).modal();
},
render : function(){
return (
  <div>
    <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.showModal}>
        Show Modal
   </button>
    <Modal ref="modal" />
  </div>
);
 }});

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```